# How do I run sklearn in Python without having Cython?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/ogrisel/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/_k_means.pyx), it looks like Cython is used to run sklearn `knn` algorithm for example.

How is it that I run it fine on my computer with 2.7.x?

Forgive me if this is a silly question, I know very little about Cython vs Python or C.

Comment: You probably installed a binary version that is already compiled --- in essence, somebody else ran Cython for you and just gave you the compiled result.

Comment: side note: even if a question is not appropriate in some way there is no need to ask for forgiveness. There is rather a need for *willing to understand why* a question might be not appropriate, in case it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much the same as you can run C code without a C compiler or Haskell code without a Haskell compiler.

Cython compiles to C that calls CPython. CPython is the standard Python interpreter, that you almost definitely are using.

If the Cython was compiled to C before you recieved it, you only need to be able to compile C with, say, `gcc` or `clang`. It's possible the C was *also* precompiled for you.

Answer (score 3):

scikit-learn ships the C and C++ code that Cython generates, so you only need C and C++ compilers to build it. Cython-generated code does not require any Cython components at runtime. The choice to ship generated code was made to keep the dependencies light, and allow developers to always use the most recent Cython.

Answer (score 0):

Cython is used to build sklearn, not run it.